# Class like a type in interface of Typescript

Tags: class, typescript, types, interface

Is it possible to use Class like a type in interface ? For example, I have a class Animal, can I use something like:

```
interface I {
    object: Animal
}
```

I've got en error on this situation:

```
class A {
     public static foo(text: string): string {
         return text;
     }
  }

interface IA {
  testProp: A;
  otherProp: any;
}

class B {
    constructor(prop: IA) {
        console.log(prop.otherProp);
        console.log(prop.testProp.foo('hello!'));
    }
}
```

**TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'A'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `typeof A`:

```
class A {
    public static foo(text: string): string {
        return text;
    }
}

interface IA {
  testProp: typeof A;
  otherProp: any;
}

class B {
    constructor(prop: IA) {
        console.log(prop.otherProp);
        console.log(prop.testProp.foo('hello!'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the foo method is static. Static can only be used on classes not object.

In your case:

```
A.foo("hello); //works
new A().foo("hello"); //doesn't work since it's an instance of A
```